# JDBCTemplate RowMapper for Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbctemplate

Server inform error

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
>   StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Comment ON
>   Comment.Account_ID=Accounts.Account_ID WHERE Comment.Place_ID=3]; The
>   column name Accounts.Account_ID is not valid.; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name
>   Accounts.Account_ID is not valid.

This is my code in DAO

```
public List<LoadCommentDTO> loadComment(int placeId) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Comment ON Comment.Account_ID=Accounts.Account_ID WHERE Comment.Place_ID="+ placeId ;
        RowMapper<LoadCommentDTO> rowMapper = new CommentRowMapper();
        List<LoadCommentDTO> listComment = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
        return listComment;
    }

    protected class CommentRowMapper implements RowMapper<LoadCommentDTO> {
        @Override
        public LoadCommentDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            LoadCommentDTO loadCommentDTO = new LoadCommentDTO();
            CommentDTO commentDTO  = new CommentDTO();
            AccountDTO accountDTO = new AccountDTO();

            accountDTO.setAccountID(rs.getInt("Accounts.Account_ID"));
            accountDTO.setAvatar_path(rs.getString("Accounts.Avatar_path"));
            accountDTO.setFirstname(rs.getString("Accounts.Firstname"));
            accountDTO.setLastname(rs.getString("Accounts.Lastname"));

            commentDTO.setAccount_Id(rs.getInt("Comment.Account_ID"));
            commentDTO.setDescription(rs.getString("CommentDescription"));
            commentDTO.setPlace_ID(rs.getInt("CommentPlace_ID"));
            commentDTO.setC_Date(rs.getString("CommentC_Date"));

            loadCommentDTO.setAccountDTO(accountDTO);
            loadCommentDTO.setCommentDTO(commentDTO);

            return loadCommentDTO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your column "Account_ID" exists with that name in the table Accounts.

Comment: Yes. already have. Because sql statement "SELECT * FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Comment ON Comment.Account_ID=Accounts.Account_ID WHERE Comment.Place_ID=3" when i put it into new query in SQL Server, it's run.

Comment: If the excpetion throw from `accountDTO.setAccountID(rs.getInt("Accounts.Account_ID"));`, you should modify it to `accountDTO.setAccountID(rs.getInt("Account_ID"));`.